# ISO 8583 Mobile Banking

Tags: android, banking, iso8583

Please let me know the below info are sufficient enough for Balance Query request and response.. I have used JPOS library to construct.. I am doing mobile banking in android.

ISO 8583 Format for the Balance Query Request

```
—-ISO MESSAGE—–
MTI : 0100
Field-2 : 070116123456789
Field-3 : 301000
Field-11 : 000001
RESULT: 0100602000000000000015070116123456789301000000001
ISO 8583 Format for the Balance Query Successful Response

—-ISO MESSAGE—–
MTI : 0110
Field-2 : 070116123456789
Field-3 : 301000
Field-4 : 5000
Field-11 : 000001
Field-12 : 024100
Field-13 : 0411
Field-39 : 00
——————–
RESULT : 0110703800000200000015070116123456789301000000000005000000001024100041100
```

Answer (score 4):

ISO 8583 defines the message format. Services developed on top of the ISO 8583 are implementation specific. You must develop to the specifications of your particular acquirer.

Answer (score 2):

ISO 8583 - Balance Inquiry, Processing Code DE 03 = 310000 | MTI = 0100